# How can i reuse a view from another application to my current application in sapui5

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I want to reuse a view of another sapui5 application (suppose xyz app) to my current sapui5 application ( suppose abc app), and i don't have idea how to achieve this. I have read something like jQuery.sap.registerModulePath() to register the components, but i am not getting idea how to implement. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you register a lib with that function. Then you use require to load it. https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm